# Windows Service not trapping error from DLL

Tags: dll, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that runs every 10 minutes.  Whenever there is an error on the DLL, the service isn't throwing an error.  How do I make it so the error propagates back to the Windows Service and have it generate an Event Viewer message, or even start the polling again?

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorMessage = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                errorMessage += " " + ex.InnerException.Message;

            eventLog1.WriteEntry(errorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            new Logging().LogMessageToFile(errorMessage, true);
        }
```

Comment: How do you know the DLL has an error? What happens? That's really important to know, if you're asking how to try to catch it with your service.

Comment: I write it to both an EventLog and a logging file.  The error is there... tried throwing it after I wrote to the logging file to no avail.

Comment: Still confused... If you're catching an exception and writing to an EventLog, then it sounds like your goal was accomplished. Don't forget that you have to refresh the Event Viewer to see new events. What are you trying to do? Do you need to do something like this? catch(Exception ex) { /* todo logging here */ throw ex; /* rethrow the exception */ }

Comment: I'll go back and rethrow after logging with "throw new Exception();" and see where it leads.  Will report back.

Comment: No, don't throw a new blank exception, the proper form is to throw the one you caught. My comment got formatted weird.

Comment: Works now... Must not be thinking that when caught, it should have been thrown after it was handled.  By the way, didn't have to do the "throw ex;", just "throw;".  Thanks djdanlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  Throw it again AFTER catching it.

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var errorMessage = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            errorMessage += " " + ex.InnerException.Message;

        eventLog1.WriteEntry(errorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        new Logging().LogMessageToFile(errorMessage, true);

        throw;
    }
```